# some websites won't respond (timeout) to requests.get. Can headers resolve?

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, python-requests

I'm new to using requests and I can't seem to get https://www.costco.com to respond to a simple requests.get command.
I don't understand why, I believe it is because it knows I'm not on a browser.

I don't get any response, not even a 404.

so I tried with a simple header and it worked on my local machine.

```
headers = {"User-Agent":
        "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:101.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/101.0"
}
page = requests.get("https://www.costco.com", headers=headers, timeout=10)
```

But when I put this in an AWS Lambda function it went back to no response.
Is there a way to know why it won't respond at all? like what headers it is after?

Note that I have no trouble getting a response from https://google.com.

Comment: A possible reason is that Costco blocks requests that come from AWS IPs, to prevent things like bot/scraping activity.

Comment: thanks, that is my suspicion as well. I'll just have to use a local container to run my app instead of AWS Lambda, but it would be good to know how to circumvent this in the future if ever needed.
Note that I am not abusing their site, just want to automate checking when a product comes to my local store